# How do I default a property of a Matlab instance with a size based on an instance variable that is set upon constructing the instance?

Tags: matlab, oop, properties, instance

I have a problem in which I want to model some physical phenomenon. This phenomenon consists of several phases, each of which may have its own governing equations (dynamics and thus no. of variables, constraints, variable boundaries, etc.). In order to group this phase's properties, I have written a class `phase`. An instance of this class has, a.o., a property called `nVars`, the number of variables in the governing equations (which may thus vary amongst instances of this class).

Now, suppose I want to have another property for this class that is called `boundaries`. Because I require the variable boundaries to be formulated in a very specific way, I also create a class `boundaries`. This class has properties `lower` and `upper`; the variables' lower and upper boundaries. However, the length of these lower and upper boundaries depend on the `phase` instance's `nVars`.

In the most general case, the lower boundaries are all `-Inf` and the upper boundaries are all `Inf`. Therefore, I want to default the values of the `boundaries` properties `lower` and `upper` to `-Inf * ones([1 nVars])` and to `Inf * ones([1 nVars])`, respectively. Now, my question is: how do I make the default value of a class property dependent on a variable (`nVars` in this case).

My first attempt:

```matlab
classdef phase
    properties 
        nVars(1, 1) double
        boundaries boundaries
    end
    methods
        function obj = phase(nVars)
            %Some constructor method
            obj.nVars = nVars;
            obj.boundaries = boundaries(obj);
        end
    end
end

classdef boundaries
    properties 
        parent phase
        lower = -Inf * ones([1 parent.nVars]);
        upper = Inf * ones([1 parent.nVars]);
    end
    methods
        function obj = boundaries(parent)
            %Some constructor method
            obj.parent = parent;
        end
    end
end
```

Alternatively, I tried defaulting the boundaries class's properties in the following way:

```matlab
classdef boundaries
    properties 
        parent phase
        lower(1, parent.nVars) double = -Inf;
        upper(1, parent.nVars) double = Inf;
    end
    methods
        function obj = boundaries(parent)
            %Some constructor method
            obj.parent = parent;
        end
    end
end
```

Can anyone help me in understanding how to assign these default values based on a variable?

Comment: Maybe you can define it to be `lower(1,:) double = -Inf`, initialize it with the right size in the constructor of `boundaries`, and then add a property listener that checks the size of `lower` and `upper` and validates it with `obj.parent.nVars` (which is only available after the constructor is called). See [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/listening-for-changes-to-property-values.html) for info on property listeners.

Comment: The answer of your question is in your title: "variable that is set **upon constructing the instance**?" ... Assign the default values in the **constructor** of your `boundaries` object. It works as good as the simple classdef default value and you can code all sorts of input checking on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
classdef phase < handle
    properties 
        nVars       double ;
        boundaries  boundaries ;
    end
    methods
        function obj = phase(nVars)
            %Some constructor method
            obj.nVars = nVars;
            obj.boundaries = boundaries(obj);
        end
    end
end

classdef boundaries
    properties 
        parent phase
        upper   double ;
        lower   double ;
    end
    methods
        function obj = boundaries( parent )
            % Assign the parent handle
            obj.parent = parent ;
            % Initialise default values for the properties
            obj.upper =  Inf * ones([1 parent.nVars]);
            obj.lower = -obj.upper ;
        end
    end
end
```

This initialise correctly:

```
>> a = phase(5)
a = 
  phase with properties:

         nVars: 5
    boundaries: [1x1 boundaries]
>> a.boundaries
ans = 
  boundaries with properties:

    parent: [1x1 phase]
     upper: [Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf]
     lower: [-Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf -Inf]
```

The `classdef` syntax which allow to define default values in the properties in a nice convenience to limit the coding effort which have to be done in the constructor (automatic checking of the input type and all sorts of input check).

However, for every default value you define in the property block, under the hood MATLAB add auto-generated code to the constructor of the object. Once the object is finally created and initialised, it makes **no difference** if the property values where assigned directly in the property block or in the constructor.

For your case, the code to add to the constructor is so trivial that it is not worth loosing time trying to find a syntax which would work in the property block. Besides, this would always fail in your case because of another issue: the passing by reference.

When you try to assign a handle to the parent object in your `boundaries` class, you were just sending **a copy** of your initial phase object. This copy would sit in the `boundaries` object but is uncoupled from the actual `phase` parent object. To be able to pass the parent object by reference you need a `handle` to this parent object, and for that you need to define the parent class as `handle`.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. Indeed, the answer is so trivial that I overlooked it. It's a shame though, I like the defaulting syntax better, because it is clear that the values are defaulted immediately when inspecting the problem. Having the default values in the constructor requires the reader to search more. 

Thanks for the addition about the `handle` class. You are saying that making the `phase` class inherit from `handle` and leaving the rest of the code intact should give me the behaviour I am looking for?

Comment: Not exactly, inheriting the `phase` class from `handle` is necessary for the `boundaries` class to be able to maintain a valid reference to its parent class. You can only hold a reference to a handle class, not to a value class. But this is independent of the initialisation method chosen for the properties.

Comment: Yes, I formulated myself unclearly. Indeed, I meant having a valid reference from one class to another with "the behaviour I am looking for". Thanks again!